# Convert mysql data to json array google line chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'm trying to create a multiple line chart using google line chart, php and mysql. I have other charts working with one line only, but I can't put the data on json right format for the multiple lines. I have the chart working when I manually add the values, see below. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much.

better mysql data view

[image]

mysql text only

```
'units','utilization','usedtime'
'0', '0', '00:00:02'
'1', '0', '00:00:02'
'2', '0', '00:00:02'
'3', '0', '00:00:02'
'4', '0', '00:00:02'
'5', '0', '00:00:02'
'6', '0', '00:00:02'
'7', '0', '00:00:02'
'0', '0', '00:01:01'
'1', '0', '00:01:01'
'2', '0', '00:01:01'
'3', '0', '00:01:01'
'4', '0', '00:01:01'
'5', '0', '00:01:01'
'6', '0', '00:01:01'
'7', '0', '00:01:01'
'0', '0', '00:02:02'
'1', '0', '00:02:02'
'2', '0', '00:02:02'
'3', '0', '00:02:02'
'4', '0', '00:02:02'
'5', '0', '00:02:02'
'6', '0', '00:02:02'
'7', '0', '00:02:02'
```

manually entered data on the google chart script

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Time', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
        ['00:00:02', 10, 15, 20, 0, 10, 0, 10, 5],
        ['00:01:01', 20, 25, 0, 30, 10, 50, 15, 25],
        ['00:02:02', 30, 15, 20, 40, 10, 60, 35, 45],
        ['00:03:02', 50, 20, 30, 50, 10, 70, 50, 20],
        ['00:04:02', 10, 10, 40, 60, 10, 80, 70, 30]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Units',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            colors: ['#0cae04', 'blue', 'red', 'green', '#4f9ee0', 'gray', 'navy', '#d3362d']
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look up Pivot Table I think you can query the database and get the data in this format

Comment: RiggsFolly, thank you for the tip and that did work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that worked for me, so I just used 2 units instead of the 7 that were on the question. I hope it helps anyone else.

**//DB**

```
include "inc/dbconnection.php";

$query = "select 
date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as usedtime, 
sum(IF(unit=0,utilization,NULL)) AS U0,
sum(IF(unit=1,utilization,NULL)) AS U1
from usage
WHERE date(timestamp) = CURDATE()
group by timestamp";

//query DB

$res = mysqli_query($dbCon1, $query);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

if ((mysqli_num_rows($res)) > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

        $stamp[] = $row['usedtime'];
        $unit0[] = $row['U0'];
        $unit1[] = $row['U1'];
    }
    //add to an array
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($stamp); $i++) {
        $chart[$i] = array((string)$stamp[$i], (int)$unit0[$i], (int)$unit1[$i]);
    }
} //end for

//close DB connection

mysqli_close($dbCon);

//convert to json

$unitusage = json_encode($chart, true);

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        //call chart function
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        //chart function
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
            data.addColumn('number', 'U0');
            data.addColumn('number', 'U1');
            //define data rows
            data.addRows(<?php echo $unitusage; ?>);
            var options = {
                title: 'Units',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                    colors: ['#0cae04', '#4f9ee0']
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>

                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```